How to populate data from json format into data table and keep datatable properties
I have been able to get data into data table from json format via ajax,But suddenly data table lost some properties that enable it to search and allow pagination on page. But the results can be viewed as an array via console.log, And all data are coming as a result on long table, But on document.ready function the table before i change the control appears well with all the functionalities
1- I tried to polulate it via js using by declaring and enable the properties as follow:
 $('#assets').DataTable({
        paging: true,
        scrollX: true,
        lengthChange : true,
        searching: true,
        ordering: true
      });

and Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from 1 total entries)
2- Alternatively
.done( function(data) {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aaData": data,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "detail_alias" },
            { "data": "points" }
        ]
    })
})

I tried different method from different sources and red datatable resouces but didn't work.
I googled for long without getting an answer

I have used the online dummy product URL for the purpose of data fetching. Update your code accordingly.
You need the adjust your data table accordingly:
$(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#assets').DataTable({
         paging: true,
            scrollX: true,
            lengthChange: true,
            searching: true,
            ordering: true,
            columns: [
                { data: 'id' },
                { data: 'name' },
                { data: 'detail_alias' },
                { data: 'points' }
            ]
        });

Furthermore, if your data returns from the backend API accordingly to the data table format feel free to remove the formatting code:
   var formattedData = data.products.map(function(product) {
                    return {
                        id: product.id,
                        name: product.title,
                        detail_alias: product.title,
                        points: product.price
                    };
                });

Refer the code below for more reference:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DataTable with JSON Data</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="assets" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Detail Alias</th>
                <th>Points</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#assets').DataTable({
         paging: true,
            scrollX: true,
            lengthChange: true,
            searching: true,
            ordering: true,
            columns: [
                { data: 'id' },
                { data: 'name' },
                { data: 'detail_alias' },
                { data: 'points' }
            ]
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://dummyjson.com/products',  // Replace with original url
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var formattedData = data.products.map(function(product) { // Not needed if data receive from backend is in format accordingly
                    return {
                        id: product.id,
                        name: product.title,
                        detail_alias: product.title,
                        points: product.price
                    };
                });
                table.clear();
                table.rows.add(formattedData);
                table.draw();
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error('AJAX Error:', {
                    status: status,
                    error: error,
                    responseText: xhr.responseText
                });
                alert('An error occurred while loading data. Please check the console for details.');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>




I have used some of your code, seems to be on the way but the table is now populated with corrects 6 records, but i can not see them visible clearly in the table, looks like i need to place each item in respective column to be shown, here is the success block @selaka-nanayakkara, please assist to get it resolved

if the answer at least partially resolves the purpose I request you mark it as correct answer and give a upvote for the love for the community. Then we can do the rest.. @Shyakalee

Hello Sir, my request isn't solved as shown i am still not yet sorted out, the results are being shown well in json format via console.log, but not able to get them populated in visually in table, please assist @Selaka Nanayakkara
